# MongoDB Atlas Device Sync client reset

Tags: mongodb, realm, atlas-device-sync

Made breaking changes in DB schema (renamed document property), so client reset is needed. I have implemented `ClientResetHandler` in realm config (just for logging for now). But none of this handlers get called. Instead I have exception `OnSessionError` callback when I update subscriptions:

`Realms.Sync.Exceptions.SessionException: Invalid query: failed to parse query: unsupported query for table "MyCollection": key "MyOldQueryKey" is not a queryable field`

Exception is obvious and self-explanatory.
The question is:
How can I reset the client and what it really means, is it some function responsibility in code, could restart or even physical re-install of the app?
Do I need to make UI prompt for existing users to physical reinstall the app (fresh install works fine)? Only device with previous app version have the issue.
Is there any way to reset the client without reinstalling the app and in what callback stage - ManualResetFallback never get called?
Where does the Realm SDK stores this queryable `old_field_name` on client side? I'm using .NET SDK.

Read several topics but there is so many options so one can easily lost:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/error-handling/client-resets/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/sync/client-reset/#std-label-dotnet-client-resets

**Update:**

```
    _config = new FlexibleSyncConfiguration(_app.CurrentUser!)
    {
            PopulateInitialSubscriptions = realm =>
            {
                realm.Subscriptions.Add(realm.All<MyCollection>().Where(x => x.OwnerId == ownerId), new SubscriptionOptions { Name = "MyCollection" });
            },
            ClientResetHandler = new RecoverOrDiscardUnsyncedChangesHandler
            {
                    OnBeforeReset = (beforeReset) => { Log.Trace("OnBeforeReset"); },
                    OnAfterRecovery = (beforeReset, afterReset) => { Log.Trace("OnAfterRecovery"); },
                    OnAfterDiscard = (beforeReset, afterReset) => { Log.Trace("OnAfterDiscard"); },
                    ManualResetFallback = resetException =>
                    {
                        // EXPECTED CALL HERE (never happen)!

                        var didReset = resetException.InitiateClientReset();
                        if (didReset) // Navigate the user back to the main page
                        else // Reset failed - notify user that they'll need to update the app
                    }
            },
            OnSessionError = (session, error) =>
            {
                Log.Error(error);

                // ENDED UP HERE!!! WHAT'S NEXT?  
            }
    };
```

Comment: Renaming a property is considered a destructive change - typically a migration would be helpful in these cases [Migration](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/model-data/change-an-object-model/#change-an-object-model---.net-sdk). What process did you use to 'rename' the document property in respects the the existing data in the property in your Realm file?

Comment: I terminated device sync, renamed a property, made changed to all documents in db, make updates in queryable fields in backend and client app, re-enable device sync. 
Clean install has no any issue only app updates. My question is, what is considered as client reset?

Comment: A client reset is an error recovery task that a client app performs when a synced realm on the server can no longer sync with the client realm. The client reset, resets the realm on the client so it matches the state of the server. So for example, a destructive change, like renaming or removing a property. The server doesn't know what to do with that situation so a client reset occurs. In your case a clean install would be a clean realm and it will sync with no issues. However, if the realm exists, there's probably data in it that doesn't match the server so the server doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Are you saying that only option in case of any property renaming is app complete uninstall and clean reinstall? That would be very painful for all customers! I would  just better prefer app update in place. In this case I do not care about unsynced local data, lost is acceptable. Main goal is to get app sync again with new version update.

Comment: There are different strategies to handle [Client Resets](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/sync/client-reset/). The important bit is the recovery process cannot handle a breaking schema change. It's up to you to determine what kind of change it is and handle accordingly. For example, if a breaking change is local, it will require a migration. See [Breaking Change](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/data-model/update-schema/#breaking-changes). Then see [Rename Property](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/model-data/define-object-model/#rename-a-property)

Comment: @Jay Yes, thanks for trying to help. I already read the documentations twice before searching for solution here. Docs didn't cover straight actions how to perform client reset in Flexible Sync mode just general strategy overview. I knowingly make breaking changes, set default ClientResetHandler in sync configuration, considering fallback to ManualRecoveryHandler but then what? There is just a comment string in docs: ` ManualResetFallback = (err) => { // Automatic reset failed; handle the reset manually here }` How to reset manualy?

Comment: I think I was more pointing to the steps of how to rename a property as if that process is followed,  the reset of the steps fall into place e.g. `Use the 
[MapTo] attribute`. That's why I initially asked what process was done to rename the property.